# Mysql connection error in wso2 apim/identity server docker

Tags: mysql, docker, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have 3 dockerfiles for WSO2 apim, identity server, and mysql. using docker-compose to run these. The corresponding docker-compose.yml is given as below:-

```
    # docker-compose version
version: "3.7"

# services/containers to be run
services:
  wso2am:
    build: ./apim
    image: wso2am:2.6.0
    ports:
      - "9443:9443"
    links:
      - mysql-db
      - wso2is-km
  wso2is-km:
    build: ./is-as-km
    image: wso2is-km:5.7.0
    ports:
      - "9444:9444"
    links:
      - mysql-db
  mysql-db:
    build: ./mysql
    image: mysql:5.7.26
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
      - "33060:33060"
```

When running without changing h2 database to mysql Identity server/ apim works fine at ports 9444/9443 respectively. Also in mysql docker created regdb/apidb sql databases from the datascripts folder in apim/identity server.

```
# Derived from official mysql image (our base image)
FROM mysql:5.7
MAINTAINER Abhilash K R <abhilash.kr@aot-technologies.com>

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD root
# Add a user
ENV MYSQL_USER wso2carbon
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD wso2carbon

# Add the content of the sql-scripts/ directory to your image
# All scripts in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ are automatically
COPY sql-scripts/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
# expose ports
EXPOSE 3306 33060
```

Added jdbc driver and added new db url as below:

```
<datasource>
            <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
            <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/regdb</url>
                    <username>wso2carbon</username>
                    <password>wso2carbon</password>
                    <driverClassName>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                    <defaultAutoCommit>true</defaultAutoCommit>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>
```

Getting the error as below:
[image]
[image]
Thinking the error is at the url jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/regdb , tried to give localhost/ip of the dockerhost also still didn0t work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the mysql connection string as below -

`<url>jdbc:mysql:jdbc:mysql://mysql-db:3306/regdb</url>`

In compose, services are reachable by their name itself. No need to use `links` etc. You can use `depends_on` or `service_healthy` in case you have interdependent services.

Ref - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#depends_on

Comment: tried the mysql-db:3306/regdb as well getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the error when connecting to user database. Could you verify whether the username and password configured for this database is correct?

Comment: yes the username and database is correct. I could connect and see the dbs through a mysql bash.